# How do I use IISNode and ASP.NET side by side

Tags: node.js, asp.net, iis, signalr, iisnode

I have a web app where I use Nodejs express with IISNode for most of the content and it works fine. However, I need a real-time system for some new functionality. I tried adding sockets.io and Websockets with IISnode and was a hit or miss, doesn't work correctly occasionally. Right now, I'm implementing the real-time part using SignalR on ASP.Net and it works perfectly. I'm wondering how I could run it side by side utilizing both apps without having to code the content part of the site in ASP.NET.
Is it possible to route a request URL to a different application? For instance, how do I make example.com/asp routed to the ASP.NET app while example.net/express goes to my nodejs app?

Comment: You can host different web apps in different IIS applications, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis so that they each can use its own tech stack. What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a site for tutorials and you should come back with specific questions.

Comment: @LexLi I wasn't aware of it. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. Please post more details information about your requirement.